# Что лучше использовать для окна вывода сообщений чата?

Tags: qt, c++

Сейчас использую QTextEdit и добавляю новые сообщения в буфер и просто показываю весь этот буфер после получения каждого сообщения. Не накладно ли это? Как ещё можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший подход - использовать очередь простую (FIFO). Вышел - идет в кэш. Как организовать кэш - другой вопрос. Хорошо, если вся история не будет висеть в памяти. А из очереди формируешь TextEdit.